# Converting millisecond to Datetime gives incorrect time

Tags: java, android, date, time

i wandted to conver a long value to formatted time.
The code i used:

```
long startTimeInSeconds = 60*60*1000*sH + 60*1000*sM + sS*1000 + sL;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss,SSS");
Date start= new Date(SU.startTime);
StartTime = dateFormat.format(start);
```

Here `sH` `sM` .. are the hours minutes .. from a string, the format was this:`"hh:mm:ss,SSS"`.
`SU.startTime` is the `startTimeInSeconds`.
`StartTime` is a String.

When i display the `StartTime` it not gives me the correct time.
For example when the `startTimeInSeconds` is `2510823`, it has to be `0:41:50,823` but i get `1:41:50,823`.
I dont know what i did wrong, if i display the hours minutes... like this:

```
int hours = (int) (SU.startTime / (60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Then i get the correct values.

Does anyone know whats the solution for this problem??

Comment: Date includes a time zone - so if your time zone if GMT + 1 (or -1, not sure) for example, it will show 1:41 instead of 0:41.

Comment: @assylias where do you live again. ;)

Comment: it might be this problem, my time zome is gmt +1, but if i set to gmt, the hour is 12, with gmt-1 the time is 11, on +1 its 1, but where is zero?:)

Comment: @executioner: You're using `hh`, which gives the 12 hour clock. If you want the 24 hour clock (which will give 00) you need `HH` rather than `hh`. (I've edited this into my answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem would be fixed by specifying a time zone, as others have suggested. However, a more subtle problem is that you're using an inappropriate type. You *only* have a duration, by the sounds of it - or *possibly* a time of day; it's unclear. Time zones shouldn't get involved here, if you can use the right type - after all, a "start time in seconds" doesn't logically have a time zone related to it.

Unfortunately Java doesn't really have the right types to cover this. You've got `Date` and `Calendar`, neither of which is appropriate. I'd suggest that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, where you could use the [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Duration.html) or [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) type based on your requirements - then use an appropriate formatter for that type, and you won't run into this issue.

Joda Time is a much better API for date/time handling in general - I would strongly advise using it in preference to the Java API wherever you can.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you also want `HH` rather than `hh` in your format string, as you want the 24 hour clock in order to show midnight as 00 rather than 12.

Comment: thank you very much, changing to HH and setting the timezone dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")) did the trick.

Comment: @executioner: But did you take my wider point? Using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` isn't *really* appropriate here. I strongly advise you to take a bit of time to make the wider change, for greater benefit in the long run.

Comment: Yes, thank you i will look upon Joda Time, and later i will change it to that, but first i wanted to implement the most used functions. Optimization will be later :)

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you are in the UK or France where the time zone in 1 Jan 1970 was GMT+1.  If you set the time zone to be "GMT" you won't have this problem.

Comment: I tried dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00")); the the hour is 12, with -1 its 11, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case of a TimeZone you use. The default is supplied to the DateFormat if you don't specify one.

Answer (score 0):

You better start using Calendar instead of date. You need to do a bit of research on that.